# How can I increase the Network LAN speed of a RT-AC68U

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

I recently purchased a RT-AC68U wireless router.

It is supposed to do 1300 Mbps over LAN. I am currently receiving 450 Mbps (which is faster than I have ever had but still not what it is supposed to do). The laptop I am testing it on is 2 feet away from the router.

The number 450 Mbps is seen when right clicking wireless network and viewing properties inside Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network and Sharing Center.

Any idea how to fix this? I think my wireless card is: Killer Wireless-N 1103 Network Adapter.

[image]

Comment: I go to Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network and Sharing Center and right click my network and I check there. I can post a picture of it. I get the feeling that my network card can't handle more than 450Mbps, is there another way to test my LAN speed?

Comment: You mention your wireless card that means your LAN speed isn't even a consideration.  Are you connected through a wired or wireless connection?

Comment: Infact the connection you indicate in the question itself is a wireless connection. You are getting about 45 Mbit/sec which is about half of what you would realistically what you should see in a 802.11N network serviced by a 802.11AC router. Your connection is limited by the wireless card you have. You should replace it with a 802.11AC USB 3.0 adapter.  The incorrect use of the word `LAN` nearly confused me

Answer (score 1):

To get the 1300Mbps WLAN PHY rate, you need a 3 spatial stream (3x3) 802.11ac WNIC in your client. You also need to make sure you're using an 80MHz wide channel on the AP, that the channel is clean, and that you're at an ideal range like 2-3m from the AP.

At this time, 1300Mbps client cards are rare, because it's hard to build 3 good antennas into a USB dongle, and no one builds/buys after-market PCIe-mini cards. Asus has a desktop-sized PCIe 1300Mbps client card.

Apple has built 1300Mbps client cards into the 2013 Retina MacBooks Pro, iMacs, and Mac Pro.

Even with an AP and client card capable of the 1300Mbps PHY rate, and even with ideal RF conditions, efficient software, and a properly-tuned TCP/IP stack, you're still not likely to see TCP throughputs above 800Mbps, and you should probably be happy if you routinely see 500Mbps. Wireless-to-wireless will only get half of that.